# Why are some format specifiers unavailable in strftime in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, strftime

I want to use the function `strftime()` from `<ctime>`  to print the time in the ISO 8601 UTC format, e.g. `2016-01-12T10:37:20Z`.

According to the standard [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/), the format string `%FT%TZ` produces the same as `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`, but Visual Studio 2010 does not know the format specifiers %F and %T. Why is that? [They seem to have forgotten them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fe06s4ak.aspx)?!

Comment: The linked site is **not** the standard. It is just a website. If you need the standard, get the official version from the ISO or search for a final draft. For C, see http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: Oh, and that is a C quiestion. Do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: I would assume it is because Visual Studio is worthless at standard compliance.

Comment: Use a standard compliant compiler!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those features were introduced to standard [C in C99](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime), and to [C++ in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime).

It seems that Visual Studio 2010 supports neither of those standards.